# Using a flag as a tallit

Tags: tzitzis, tallit-gadol, symbols-symbology, tallit-katan

Would a rectangular cloth be halachically invalid as a tallit (kattan or gadol) because it happens to be a national flag? Would any other specific pattern or logo make a difference?

Comment: Does the flag have four corners? What material is it made of?

Comment: What about drawing a blue Star of David in the middle of a Tallit with blue stripes?

Comment: What country/state/city/organization?

Comment: The flag has 4 corners. As for materials, even if it were shatnez (which I inferred was your concren), it would be permissible as tzitzit may contain shatnez

Comment: You did not infer correctly nor is your statement about shaatnez entirely accurate

Comment: Our questions all can basically be summarized thus: "Why are you asking the question?"

Comment: Also, @DoubleAA's specific question about materials matters beyond sha'atnez (which, he notes correctly, you seem to misunderstand - which is ok, since it's a common misconception).  Is it paper? Is it polyester?

Comment: What imagery does it contain, flags such as that of India contain religious symbols, which might become problematic, if for no other reason than maarit ayin.

Comment: Would U.S., Canada, or Israeli flag be a problem. These flags have 4 corners and are nylon. The U.S. flag previously hung on a pole.

Comment: @SethJ I think I see an application.  Olympic atheletes, when they win their race, event, etc., often wrap themselves in a large national flag.  Query:  Would the person be wearing the flag as a beged or as an ornament?  If he does not attempt to  use it as permanent clothing, but merely as a decoration to celebrate, does this four-cornered garment need tzitzis?

Comment: @DanF, those details make this a very different (or at least a much narrower) question than the one you posed.

Comment: Answer: I don't think it would be invalid.  But I'm not a rabbi, and this question appears to be asking for a p'sak.

Comment: The concept is, I think, fairly simple. I like being creative. So, I thought it would be different to take a U.S. or Israeli flag - plain flag that usually files on a pole, and put tzitzit on it so I can use it as a tallit for davening. That's all. I'm not wearing the flag or using this for anything else. After the tzitzit go on, I won't even fly it on a pole. It will be only a davening tallit.

Comment: @DanF to update on a different comment I added here earlier, I have discovered that there are actually various opinions addressing the question of clothing made of synthetic material therefore you might want to ask an Orthodox rabbi whom you trust and admire regarding that particular earlier comment

Answer (score 4):

From the Shulchan Aruch hilchos tzitzs 10:11 we learn that a scarf is not mechyuav to have tzits even though it is draped on the shoulders it is still considered a head beged(see the Biur halacha).In order for there to be a chiyuv of tzitzs it has to be considered a beged which is usually worn as such. If a person would wrap a flag around himself then certainly one would not need tzitzs since it surely does not have a shem beged since no one wears a flag.However ,if you decide to take a flag and you designate it as a beged(and you wear it on a constant basis) then it would be mechyuav.

Comment: See my comment, above. I only plan on using this flag as a tallit for davening, so it's not a "permanent" beged.

Comment: That is exactly what a tallis is,you think anyone would wear a long cloth ,it only is for davening