# Does an Israeli flag require tzitzis?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis

I frequently people wearing flags draped over their shoulders in shows of solidarity with Israel. It occurred to me that they were the flag in a not-dissimilar way from how I wear a tallis, and the flag is a four-cornered... well, if not garment, *thing*. Would the flag require tzitzis if it is to be worn over shoulders?

Comment: Great question!  I would think it comes down to whether that is considered "wearing" it in the same way as a garment.  I imagine that there might be arguments on that both ways.  I once asked my Rav if I use a rectangular blanket to keep warm during the day whether it needs tzitzis and was told not, I think he said because it isn't really clothing, so my gut feeling is that the same probably applies here.

Comment: Highly related (possible duplicate) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1701 @yehuda

Comment: @KirkBellard Not a duplicate because a blanket is not "worn," per se - definitely not in a way that directly resembles a tallis the way that wearing a flag does.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37457/using-a-flag-as-a-tallit

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/5896